# How to do the square root of X operation in Qiskit

Tags: algorithm, quantum-computing, qiskit, cirq

I'm trying to do the Bell Inequality Test in Qiskit but to do that you need preform the controlled negative square root of X operation. An example of this in Cirq is

```
cirq.CNOT(bob_ref, bob)**-0.5
```

I tried to do something similar in Qiskit and it gave me an error

```
cir.cx(bob_ref, bob)**-0.5
```

Comment: This question is probably better suited here: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com